# How to compute an Ant fileset in Groovy based on a specification provided in an XML node

Tags: xml, gradle, groovy, ant

I have an XML document that contains [Ant Fileset](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) definitions. I would like to use those definitions in a Gradle plugin written in Groovy. Given that both Groovy and Gradle have strong support for Ant, I am looking for the easiest way to compute fileset.

```
import org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection
import org.gradle.api.file.Directory
import org.w3c.dom.Node

FileCollection computeFileset(Directory resolveHere, Node antFileSetSpec)
```

I am also happy to use [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) and GPath if that helps.

Comment: The first link provided the question does not seem to work. Would like to provide the sample xml and mention which data needs to be extracted?

Comment: Gradle has robust file collections of its own. You're better off just logically reproducing it with a FileTree.

Comment: @Rao What issue are experiencing accessing the link?

Comment: @lu.koerfer I would like an effective design and the space of possible approaches seems large. I do not feel that your second question sounds constructive. In case you are serious: The answer is no. I was using this for precision to express my effective goal.

Comment: @CAustin I am aware of FileTree. The source file I am processing is in XML format, so I would then write a bridge between that representation and the Gradle in memory model. Given that AntBuilder allows some property access, I was hoping I could evaluate in an Ant context.